# Makefile - cannot find shared library

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

I have a Makefile for a c++ Linux project:

```
MODE ?= dbg
DIR = ../../../../../somdir/$(MODE)

SRC_FILES = a.cpp b.cpp
H_FILES = a.h

LDFLAGS += -L$(DIR)/lib/linux '-Wl,-R$$ORIGIN'
CPPFLAGS = -I$(DIR)/include
LIBRARIES = -lsomeso

ifeq (rel, $(MODE))
  CFLAGS = -Wall -g -DNDEBUG
else
  CFLAGS = -Wall -ansi -pedantic -Wconversion -g -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
endif

sample: $(SRC_FILES) $(H_FILES) Makefile
    g++ $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBRARIES) $(SRC_FILES) -o sample
```

when i run 'make' it builds the project, with no errors.
but when i run the project it complains that:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libsomeso.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The path that i give in DIR goes to the folder where the shared object is held(relatively to where the makefile is placed), and if it was the wrong path why didn't it complain during the make process.

does someone know what am i missing?

Thanks 
Matt

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
LDFLAGS += -L$(DIR)/lib/linux '-Wl,-R$$ORIGIN'
```

The above should be:

```
LDFLAGS += -L$(DIR)/lib/linux -Wl,-R$(DIR)/lib/linux '-Wl,-R$$ORIGIN'
```

That is, for each non-standard dynamic library location `-L` a corresponding `-Wl,-R` should be specified. `$ORIGIN` is needed to locate dynamic libraries relative to the executable, not sure if you need it here.

People often advise using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. This is a bad advice, in my opinion, because it makes deployment more complicated.

Comment: still very helpful in the future

Answer (score 2):

When you run your application, location of `libsomeso.so` should be in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.  Try running program like this:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="path_to_libsomeso_so:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" myprogram
```

Here `path_to_libsomeso_so` is full path to a **directory** where `libsomeso.so` is located, and `myprogram` is your program executable.  Note, that you should specify path to a directory containing `libsomeso.so`, not to `libsomeso.so` file itself.

Answer (score 1):

The trouble is not during compilation time. Everything goes fine. There's a problem at runtime.

Indeed, your program has been linked with a shared object library. Therefore, at runtime, it need to load this shared object file. During compilation, you instructs the compiler where this file was with the `-L` flag.

For the runtime, you have to set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable to point to the directory where your `libsomeso.so` file resides.

Alternatively, you can place this file in one of the standard directory where these shared object files are searched for: `/usr/local/lib`, `/usr/lib`, `/lib`, but this should be what you'll do for the final distributed version of your library.

Answer (score 1):

As told from Maxim Egorushkin, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is a bad choice. Meanwhile, using `-L$(your lib path) -l$(your lib name)` gcc/g++ argument to link shared library isn't a good choice. Because, after build the exe, you should told exe where the shared library directory is. By default, executable file only search shared library at `/usr/lib` or `/usr/local/lib`. Although, you have told makefile where the shared library is when build the executable file. But when you execute this exe file, they are different.
However, link static library don't have such problem.

So, the best way to deal with your problem is change the way you link your custom shared file. Like this:

```
DYNAMIC_LIB_DIR = ../lib (your lib path ,this is a example)

OBJLIBS = xxx.so (your lib name)

gcc/g++ -o exe_name sourcefile/object_file $(DYNAMIC_LIB_DIR)/$(OBJLIBS)
```

Comment: this works for me, the answer should get more upvotes

Answer (score 0):

## Refresh that dynamic library cache!

After adding a custom, non-standard library to `/usr/local/lib`, first check that `/usr/local/lib` is listed under `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/libc.conf`.

Then, finish off with a dynamic link library cache refresh:

```
$ sudo ldconfig
```